# Chain rule, partial derivative and inner product?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

[image]

How is the chain rule applied here and result as trace?

I know $tr(XY)$ is a standard inner product on symmetric matrix. Is there any kind of generalization of chain rule that involves inner product that consistent with the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathrm{Spd}(p)$ define the open set of symmetric positive definite $p \times p$ real matrices. The first thing you may be interested in is the differential of the mapping
$$ \log \det : \mathrm{Spd}(p) \to \mathbb{R}. $$
Let $\boldsymbol\Sigma \in \mathrm{Spd}(p)$. If $\mathrm{D}_{\boldsymbol\Sigma} \det$ denotes the differential of $\det$ at $\boldsymbol\Sigma$, you can show that :
$$ \mathrm{D}_{\boldsymbol\Sigma} \det \cdot \mathbf{H} = \mathrm{tr}\Big( \mathrm{Com}(\boldsymbol\Sigma)^{\top} \mathbf{H} \Big) $$
where $\mathrm{Com}(\boldsymbol\Sigma)$ denotes the comatrix of $\boldsymbol\Sigma$. Using the chain rule, you get that :

$$ \mathrm{D}_{\boldsymbol\Sigma} \big( \log \circ \det \big) = \mathrm{D}_{\det(\boldsymbol\Sigma)} \log \circ \mathrm{D}_{\boldsymbol\Sigma} \det. $$
Given that $\mathrm{Com}(\boldsymbol\Sigma)^{\top}\boldsymbol\Sigma = \boldsymbol\Sigma \mathrm{Com}(\boldsymbol\Sigma)^{\top} = \det(\boldsymbol\Sigma) \mathrm{I}_{p}$, you get :
$$ \mathrm{D}_{\boldsymbol\Sigma} \log \det \cdot \mathbf{H} = \frac{1}{\det(\boldsymbol\Sigma)} \mathrm{tr}\Big( \mathrm{Com}(\boldsymbol\Sigma)^{\top} \mathbf{H} \Big) = \mathrm{tr}\big( \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1} \mathbf{H} \big).$$

Then, let $\phi : \mathrm{dom}(f) \to \mathrm{Spd}(p)$ be the mapping such that : $$\forall \mathbf{x} \in \mathrm{dom}(f), \, \phi(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{F}_{0} + x_{1} \mathbf{F}_{1} + \ldots + x_{n} \mathbf{F}_{n}. $$
Then :

$$ f = \log\det \circ \phi. $$

Using the chain rule again, you get that for $\mathbf{x} \in \mathrm{dom}(f)$ :

$$ \mathrm{D}_{\mathbf{x}} \big( \log\det \circ \phi \big) = \mathrm{D}_{\phi(\mathbf{x})}(\log\det) \circ \mathrm{D}_{\mathbf{x}}\phi. \tag{$\star$} $$

Finally, let $(\mathbf{e}_{1},\ldots,\mathbf{e}_{n})$ denote the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then, by definition :

$$ \forall i \in \lbrace 1,\ldots,n \rbrace, \, \forall \mathbf{x} \in \mathrm{dom}(f), \; \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathrm{D}_{\mathbf{x}} f \cdot \mathbf{e}_{i}.  $$

Using $(\star)$, you obtain that for all $i \in \lbrace 1,\ldots,n \rbrace$ and for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathrm{dom}(f)$ :

> $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathrm{D}_{\phi(\mathbf{x})}(\log\det) \cdot \mathbf{F}_{i} = \mathrm{tr}\big( \phi(\mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{F}_{i} \big). $$

This is the formula which is given in your post, with $\mathbf{F} = \phi(\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: Thanks @jibounet, so the result, involving inner product of two matrix, is due to this specific example, right? And $D_x \phi \cdot e_i = F_i$, I believe is from some reference on matrix derivative right? Any reference useful on these matrix derivative and derivative on det?

Comment: @JoeLi : You could compute $\mathrm{D}_{\mathbf{x}} \phi \cdot \mathbf{e}_i$ from its definition :
$$ \mathrm{D}_{\mathbf{x}} \phi \cdot \mathbf{e}_{i} = \lim \limits_{t \to 0} \frac{ \phi(\mathbf{x} + t \mathbf{e}_i) - \phi(\mathbf{x}) }{t} = \mathbf{F}_i. $$
Regarding the differential of $\det$ or $\log\det$, I guess you could find this in any good book on multivariate differential calculus.